# Pandas dataframe range check using between and rolling

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have to consider nth row and check n+1 to n+3 rows, if it is in the range of (nth row value)-0.5 to (nth row value)+0.5, `and(&)` the results of 3 rows.

```
    A    result
0   1.1     1      # 1.2 1.3 and 1.5 are in range of 0.6 to 1.6, ( 1 & 1 & 1)
1   1.2     0      # 1.3 and 1.5 are in range of 0.7 to 1.7, but not 2, hence ( 1 & 0 & 0)  
2   1.3     0      # 1.5 and 1 are in range of 0.8 to 1.8, but not 2 ( 1 & 0 & 1)
3   1.5     
4   2.0  
5   1.0     
6   2.5     
7   1.8  
8   4.0     
9   4.2  
10  4.5     
11  3.9     

df = pd.DataFrame( {
   'A': [1.1,1.2,1.3,1.9,2,1,2.5,1.8,4,4.2,4.5,3.9]
    } )
```

I have done some research on the site, but couldn't able to find exact syntax. I tried using `rolling` function for taking 3 rows and use `between` function check range and then `and` the results. Could you please help here.

```
s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4])
s.rolling(2).between(s-1,s+1)
```

getting error :
AttributeError: 'Rolling' object has no attribute 'between'

Comment: Please show us what you've tried, the output that attempt produces and how that output is different than the output you are wanting.

Comment: I have tried few things, but got error [ edited  ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also achieve the result without using `rolling()` while keep using `.between()`, as follows:

```
df['result'] =  (
                    (df['A'].shift(-1).between(df['A'] - 0.5, df['A'] + 0.5)) & 
                    (df['A'].shift(-2).between(df['A'] - 0.5, df['A'] + 0.5)) & 
                    (df['A'].shift(-3).between(df['A'] - 0.5, df['A'] + 0.5))
                ).astype(int)
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

      A  result
0   1.1       1
1   1.2       0
2   1.3       0
3   1.5       0
4   2.0       0
5   1.0       0
6   2.5       0
7   1.8       0
8   4.0       1
9   4.2       0
10  4.5       0
11  3.9       0
```

Answer (score 0):

Rolling windows tend to be quite slow in pandas. One quick solution can be to generate a dataframe with the values of the windows per row:

```
df_temp = pd.concat([df['A'].shift(i) for i in range(-1, 2)], axis=1)
df_temp
      A    A    A
0   1.2  1.1  NaN
1   1.3  1.2  1.1
2   1.9  1.3  1.2
3   2.0  1.9  1.3
4   1.0  2.0  1.9
5   2.5  1.0  2.0
6   1.8  2.5  1.0
7   4.0  1.8  2.5
8   4.2  4.0  1.8
9   4.5  4.2  4.0
10  3.9  4.5  4.2
11  NaN  3.9  4.5
```

Then you can check per row if the value is in the desired range:

```
df['result'] = df_temp.apply(lambda x: (x - x.iloc[0]).between(-0.5, 0.5), axis=1).all(axis=1).astype(int)

      A  result
0   1.1       0
1   1.2       1
2   1.3       0
3   1.9       0
4   2.0       0
5   1.0       0
6   2.5       0
7   1.8       0
8   4.0       0
9   4.2       1
10  4.5       0
11  3.9       0
```